# Qml application closing issue

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qqmlapplicationengine

I'm building one qml application and I printing console log's every where but if I minimize application and try to close from taskbar how will I capture that close event in console log. I'm using QT 5.13 version.

```
Component.onCompleted: {
       Qt.application.activeChanged.connect(function() {
           if (!Qt.application.active) {
               console.log("Application closed from taskbar")
           }
       })
   }
```

I tried this above code but this code is printing console log based on visibility if i minimize the application then it's printing which is wrong

Answer (score -1):

Application should emit [`aboutToQuit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) signal when it is about to quit.

To QML it is exposed as `Application` singleton that you can use like:

```js
    import QtQuick

    Window {
        id: root
        visible: true
        width: 800
        height: 680
    
        title: `${Application.name} (${Application.version})`
    
        Connections {
            target: Application
            function onAboutToQuit() {
                console.log("Bye!")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: QML Connections: Detected function "onAboutToQuit" in Connections element. This is probably intended to be a signal handler but no signal of the target matches the name.

I'm getting this error

Comment: Odd. Are you not using Qt 6? It can be was missing in earlier versions.

Comment: No, I'm using Qt5.13 
Can you please give supporting code for this

Comment: I do not have Qt5 atm, sorry, but trust that such signal was there so I would first try `Qt.application.aboutToQuit.connect()` Put your Qt version into question, no one will search it from comments.